# Xcode 4.6.1 install hangs at "Installing - less than one minute" on Lion

Tags: xcode

I have been trying to update to Xcode 4.6.1 (from 4.6) on OS X 10.7.5.  The install gets most of the way through, then hangs out at "Installing - less than one minute" indefinitely.  Based on old threads about similar problems I've ensured iTunes and iTunesHelper are both not running.  I've restarted and tried again.  What else can I try or look into?

[image]

...

and I wonder if this has anything to do with it?

[image]

Comment: The developer log in is clearly down at the moment (and has been for more than 20 minutes). I don't know if anyone can get in if they were logged in before the authentication part of the system went down, but it could be related. Now, that being said, it's quite odd for the LaunchPad + App Store download to depend on developer.apple.com being up to install the package itself. I'd expect it to check in for downloading the simulator or getting your dev certificates from Apple - but not to install the tools.

Comment: @bmike - I agree, would be weird... BUT, I could imagine maybe it finish install by starting up and trying to sync up with developer account?  totally making that up but seems remotely plausible...

Comment: So - we all know Apple uses a CDN for App Store downloads, so it's entirely possible the Dev servers are part of Xcode's CDN forest.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this case appears to be that the developer site was down.  Once it came up, install proceeded without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have downloaded the full installation package, cancel setup, turn off Wi-Fi and restart installation. Setup will complete normally.

My understanding is that the setup skip the 'connect to dev site' step.